# How to save a search Query (Copying the file and Saving )

Tags: php

I want to copy the file http://searchr.us/Testing/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT to 
http://searchr.us/Testing/search/SEARCHED+TEXT.html

How do i do this?

NOTE:The source of http://searchr.us/Testing/search/SEARCHED+TEXT.html should be the same as http://searchr.us/Testing/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT

Indirectly I'm just saving a query so that I can keep a track of them!

Answer (score 0):

Hope i've get you right: you want to store output of any query into file. You can manage this with output buffering.

In the begining of script wright:

```
ob_start(); // start buffering
```

This turns buffering on.

At the eng of page wright something like this ($query is text of query):

```
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush(); // this turns off buffering and sends buffered content to output
$fp = fopen("{$query}.html","w");
fwrite($fp,$html);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: A file is being opened but nothing in it !!